# How to write one function to delete from multiple sql tables using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am implementing a student database project which has multiple tables such as student,class,section etc

I wrote a delete_table function which takes parameters table name and value to delete a row from a specific table but there seems to be some sort of syntax error in my code :

```
def delete_tables(tab_name,attr,value):
    c.execute("delete from table=:tab_name where attribute=:attr is value=:value ",{'tab_name':tab_name, 'attr': attr, 'value': value})
```

input : 
delete_tables('section','sec_name','S1')

error text :

c.execute("delete from table=:tab_name where attribute=:attr is value=:value ",{'tab_name':tab_name, 'attr': attr, 'value': value})

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "table": syntax error

I've tried all mentioned answers and what y'all are suggesting is that it'll also be insecure even if it works out. So Do i Have to write functions to delete every table individually instead of going for one single function, and is there any other alternative to this problem where I need not keep on writing n functions for n number of tables?????
Thanks in Advance :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use parametrized queries (that `:tab_name`) on things others than values (? not sure I am using the right term):  table names, column names and SQL keywords are **forbidden**.

- `where age > :max_age` is OK.
- `where :some_col > :max_age` is not.
- `where age :comparison_operator :max_age` is not OK.

Now, you **can** build your own query using string concatenation or f strings, but...   this is a massive, massive SQL injection risk.  See [Bobby Tables](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiN_bvvvsboAhUOpp4KHV1JBEsQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fxkcd.com%2F327%2F&usg=AOvVaw0n_9VFh_1CF8JASrAo9Ni9)  Not to mention that concatenating values into SQL query strings quickly runs into issues when you have to deal with characters, numbers or None.  (None => NULL, characters need quotes, numbers dont).

You could possibly build a query using string substitutions that accept only known values for the table and column names and then drives the delete criteria value using a parametrized query on `:value`.

(While this seems restrictive, letting a random caller determine which tables to delete is just not safe in the least).

Something like:

```
delete_tables(tab_name,attr,value):

   safe_tab_name = my_dict_of_known_table_names[tab_name]

   safe_attr = my_dict_of_known_column_names[attr]

                         # you have to `=`, not `is` here 
   qry = f"delete from {safe_tab_name} where {safe_attr} = :value "

   # not entirely sure about SQLite's bind/parametrized syntax.
   # look it up if needed.
   c.execute(qry, dict(value = value))
```

Assuming a user only enters value directly, that at least is protected from SQL injection.

Comment: So could you help me with building a query with substitutions or is there really another way by which this is implemented in databases with multiple tables in real world?

Comment: Oh, I think you can proceed on your own from here - all you're missing is the dictionaries `{"mytable1": "mytable1", "mytable2": "mytable2"}.  In the real world?  Something like this can be used, but really, the sql injection bit is very very much of a problem.  Don't take shortcuts on it - anything coming from users needs to use :var parametrized query format *not string building*.  It's really very used as an exploit and because it is, it is an instant flag that the coder is incompetent when they use it.  If you're learning that's fine not to know.  But not later on.

Comment: the dictionaries are there to make sure only known tables are being sent as a parameters, not something like `column2; select * from passwords; --`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score -1):

```py
def delete_tables(tab_name, attr, value):
    c.execute("delete from " + tab_name + "where " + attr + " = " + value)
```

I think something like that will work, the issue is that you are trying to modify an attribute but its name is always `attribute`, for that you would like to make it a parameter in order to properly handle it.

Hope it helped.

#### Edit:

Check this [SQLite python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

What the c.execute does is to 'execute' a SQL query, so, you can make something like `c.execute("select * from clients")` if you have a `clients` table.

`execute` makes a query and brings you the result set (if it is the case), so if you want to delete from your table using a normal SQL query you would type in the console `delete from clients where client_id = 12` and that statement will delete the client with id equal to 12.

Now, if you are using SQLite in python, you will do

`c.execute("delete from clients where client_id = 12")`

but as you wish it to be for any table and any field (attribute) it turns in the table name, the field name and the value of that field being variables.

```py
tableName = "clients"
field = "client_id"
value = "12" #must be string because you would have to cast it from int in the execute
"""
if value is a varchar you must write
value = "'12'" because the '' are needed.
"""
c.execute("delete from " + tableName + " where " + field + " = " + value)
```

and in the top of that, as you want it to be a function

```py
def delete_tables(tableName, field, value):
    c.execute("delete from " + tableName+ "where " + field + " = " + value)
```

#### Edit 2:

[aaron's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6725583/aaron) comment is true, it is not secure, the next step you would do is

```py
def delete_tables(tab_name, attr, value):
    #no ':value' (it limits the value to characters)
    c.execute("delete from :tab_name where :attr = :value",
        {'tab_name': tab_name, 'attr': attr, 'value':value})
```

It is from [Vatsal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8350935/vatsal-agrawal) answer

Comment: can you tell me what is +attr_name+ I'm a beginner so I don't understand it , and also this code gave me a different error that said 1 missing argument though ive given all three. Thanks!

Comment: this is not secure, you are just asking for people to do SQL injection

Comment: I have tried using both the edits and its giving me syntax errors and I wasn't able to lookup a solution online I might have to write many delete functions I suppose but the that would be a problem in implementing the interface because i'll have to make that  many buttons, Thanks :))

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a look at what will be the exact SQL command that will be executed in the python method.
For the method call delete_tables('section', 'sec_name', 'S1') the SQL command that will be generated will be

```
delete from table=section where attribute=sec_name is value=S1
```

This will be an invalid command in SQL. The correct command should be

```
delete from section where sec_name='S1'
```

So you need to change your python function accordingly. The changes that need to be done should be as follows:

```
def delete_tables(tab_name, attr, value):
    c.execute("delete from :tab_name where :attr = ':value'",
        {'tab_name': tab_name, 'attr': attr, 'value':value})
```

Comment: This is giving me a syntax error similar to the on I previously had, so maybe the syntax is wrong could you suggest something else?                                                                 c.execute("delete from :tab_name where :attr = ':value'",  {'tab_name': tab_name, 'attr': attr, 'value':value})
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ":tab_name": syntax error